# How to calculate the joint probability from two normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ both normally distributed as $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (they have the same distribution).

$X$ and $Y$ are dependent. They are defined from other random variables A, B and C also with gaussian distribution:
$X$ = $A - B + const$ and
$Y$ = $-A + C + const$.

A, B and C are independent and also equally distributed as $N(0, \sigma_2^2)$.

I want to calculate $P(X < x, Y < y)$.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are they independent or not?

Comment: @Ant Yes they are dependent as they are defined from another (the same for both) variable.

Comment: I'm sorry but you have to try to be more clear, what you've written does not make sense. The distribution of the vector $(X,Y)$ (and hence $P(X < x, Y < y)$) depends on how $X$ and $Y$ are connected. If they are independent, for example, then $(X,Y)$ is a multivariate normal random variable and you can explicitly calculate it's density.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Okay. Are $A, B$ and $C$ independent?

Comment: Yes, yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is easy to see that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly gaussian; every linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is in fact normal, thanks to the fact that $A$ $B$ and $C$ are independent.

Note also that the *const* you've been writing in the definition of $X$ and $Y$ is actually $\mu$.

Anyhow, you just need to calculate the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ (which is pretty easy to do) and you'll have a [multivariate norma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)l random variable, for which we know a lot (its density, for example).

On the other hand, just like in the case of a normal in one dimension, is not possible to find an explicit formula for $P(X < x, Y < y)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If $X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)$ then $$X+Y\sim N(\mu_x+\mu_y,\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y)$$
$$X-Y\sim N(\mu_x-\mu_y,\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y)$$
$$X+const\sim N(\mu_x+const,\sigma^2_x)$$

Comment: Yes I know that so I know what the distributions of my X and Y are. But that doesn't help in computing the joint distribution.

Comment: @PedroFerreira Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent what is your difficulty in calculating the joint? Of course, in that case you will not get something with the pretty face